# How to identify failed records from "insert into select..." statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have query like this-

```
insert into [EPDIT_Prov_Master](    
[provider_id]
      ,[run_cd]
      ,[data_src_txt]
      ,[provider_type_cd]
      ,[rec_add_dts]
      ,[rec_upd_dts]
      ,rec_created_by_ind
      ,rec_upd_by_ind)
select distinct    
provider_id,
@runcode as a
,@datasource as b,
par_ind,
GETDATE(),
GETDATE()
,@createdby
,@createdby
from [epdb_master_staging] t
```

Is it possible to get those records which could not be inserted due to any type of error like data type mismatches etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Insert is atomic operation. So, to find such errors, you must make inserts by one row at a time.